correct elisp code to create frameset registers?
If I evaluate this:
(frameset-to-register "r")
then r is created as an empty register (try to jump to it afterwards!), whereas I'd like it to contain the frameset configuration just like C-x r f r would. Does anyone know how?

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

So "r" should be replaced by ?r because this is the correct syntax for characters, which is what frameset-to-register requires.

Not only for this function, but also for any function that takes a register as argument. See Basic char syntax  in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual (also, and preferably, accessible in Emacs with C-h g(elisp)RET to select the Emacs Lisp Reference manual, and then i syntax for char RET to go to the relevant section).
